# SQLAlchemy relationship to child with 2 ForeinKeys from same parent column

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` model and a `Conversation` model

```
class Conversation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'conversations'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user1 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), unique=False, nullable=False)
    user2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), unique=False, nullable=False)
    date = Column(DateTime, unique=False, nullable=False, default=dt.utcnow)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = Column(String, unique=False, nullable=True)
```

Im trying to add a `relationship()` to User model which should return all conversations where `Conversation.user1` or `Conversation.user2` is the selected `User`

I tried:

```
conversations = relationship('Conversation', backref="Users")
```

Which results to this error when I was trying to get the `User`:

> AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between
>   parent/child tables on relationship User.conversations - there are
>   multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the
>   'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which
>   should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent
>   table.

I realized I have to specify columns..

So I tried:

```
conversations = relationship(Conversation, foreign_keys=[Conversation.user1, Conversation.user2], backref="Users")
```

and

```
conversations = relationship(Conversation, foreign_keys='[Conversation.user1, Conversation.user2]', backref="Users")
```

and again same error!

After that I tried:

```
conversations = relationship(Conversation, foreign_keys=Conversation.user1 or Conversation.user2, backref="Users")
```

Which returned this error on commiting my `Conversation` object:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Again I tried to use this:

```
conversations = relationship(Conversation, foreign_keys=['Conversation.user1', 'Conversation.user2'], backref="Users")
```

And it gave me this error on getting the `User` object:

> ArgumentError: Column-based expression object expected for argument
>   'foreign_keys'; got: 'Conversation.user1', type class 'str'

Also I tried to get only one specific column by defining it using `foreign_keys` but it gave me the same `RecursionError`

I know I can do it by adding a method to `User` class like:

```
def conversations(self):
    return session.query(Conversation).filter(Conversation.user1 == self.id or Conversation.user2 == self.id).all()
```

But it's important for me to do it using `relationship()`..

Is it possible ?

If it is, how !?

Comment: Have you tried using `primaryjoin` instead of `foreign_keys`? Then you can specify whatever join criteria you want for the relationship.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions

Comment: @jbch `primaryjoin` whould get only one column, then It gives me either conversations that have the same user on user1 or user2

Comment: @jbch I tried `primaryjoin="or_(User.id == Conversation.user1, User.id == Conversation.user2)"` but it gave me `RecursionError`